# How can i convert multi row string array to int array

Tags: python, arrays

I have and array such that

```
[['0'], ['1', ' 0'], ['13', ' 12', ' 0'], ['17', ' 16', ' 10', ' 0'], ['16', ' 15', ' 8', ' 1', ' 0'], ['13', ' 12', ' 4', ' 5', ' 4', ' 0'], ['12', ' 11', ' 6', ' 11', ' 10', ' 6', ' 0']]
```

how can I convert all elements in every array to int without using loop

at the end I want an array such that

```
[[0], [1,0], [13, 12, 0], [17, 16, 10, 0], [16, 15, 8, 1, 0], [13, 12, 4, 5, 4, 0], [12, 11, 6, 11, 10, 6, 0]]
```

Comment: Is numpy allowed (to flatten)? Are list comprehension allowed?

Comment: Looks like a all array contains strings

Comment: Yes np is allowed

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
a = [['0'], ['1', ' 0'], ['13', ' 12', ' 0'], ['17', ' 16', ' 10', ' 0'], ['16', ' 15', ' 8', ' 1', ' 0'], ['13', ' 12', ' 4', ' 5', ' 4', ' 0'], ['12', ' 11', ' 6', ' 11', ' 10', ' 6', ' 0']]
new_array_with_ints = ast.literal_eval(str(a).replace("'",""))
```

Is one way you could i guess (although arguably there are still loops)

Comment: I still get str array